# Получение типа из подкласса. Полиморфизм C#

Tags: c#, ооп, полиморфизм

Доброго времени суток, столкнулся с такой проблемой. Есть абстрактный класс `ViewModel`, который содержит логику добавления данных в коллекцию для отображения в GUI.

```
public abstract class ViewModel {

    public ObservableCollection<IModel> Data { get; set; }
    protected abstract IModel createObject(SqlDataReader reader);

    protected void selectData(string query) {
         // ...
         // Логика получения reader
         // ...
         IModel item = this.createObject(reader);
         this.Data.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Также есть классы моделек, все они реализую интерфейс `IModel`, код приводить не буду, в нем нет необходимости. Класс реализующий `ViewModel` выглядит так:

```
public class UsersViewModel : ViewModel {

    public UsersViewModel() {
        string query = "SELECT TOP 300 * FROM users ORDER BY reputation DESC";
        this.selectData(query);
    }

    protected override IModel createObject(SqlDataReader reader) {
        return new User(reader);
    }
}
```

Проблема собственно в методе `createObject`. Во всех подклассах он делает одну единственную вещь: возвращает экземпляр класса модели. Мне бы хотелось от него избавится. И сделать так, что бы в абстрактном классе `ViewModel` метод `selectData` сам создавал тот объект модели, какой нужно, а какой именно, он бы узнавал из подкласса. Метод должен выглядеть примерно так:

```
protected void selectData(string query) {
     // Логика получения reader
     IModel item = new Тип_Модели_из_подкласса(reader);
     this.Data.Add(item);
}
```

Кажется мне, что проблему можно решить с помощью обобщений, но не знаю как. Или создать в подклассе свойство, которое будет уточнять какую именно реализацию интерфейса `IModel` нужно использовать. Как мне это реализовать? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: класс родитель не должен знать о классе наследнике. Потому из соображений читаемости лучше оставить как есть. Хотя может я не верно понял класс "User" заставляет сомневаться(откуда он и зачем).

Comment: Вот в PHP, к примеру есть позднее статическое связывание, там можно написать new static(), но если бы так же было и в c#, это немного не то.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну например, один из методов такой:

```
public abstract class ViewModelImpl<T> : ViewModel where T : IModel
{
    protected void selectData(string query)
    {
        // Логика получения reader
        IModel item = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), reader);
        this.Data.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Ну и наследуйте конкретные классы от `ViewModelImpl<T>` с нужным типом `T`.

(Если бы конструктор `T` был без параметров, можно было бы обойтись без рефлексии.)

---

Для лучшей читаемости можно вынести метод:

```
    private T CreateModelItem(SqlDataReader reader)
    {
        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), reader);
    }

    protected void selectData(string query)
    {
        // Логика получения reader
        IModel item = CreateModelItem(reader);
        this.Data.Add(item);
    }
```

Впрочем, у вас этот вспомогательный метод уже есть, он называется `createObject`.

Comment: А вот теперь я начинаю слоняться к мнению первого комментатора. Читаемость в данном случае сильно падает.

Comment: @Klym: Это да, рефлексия обычно плохо читаема. Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Ну зато теперь этот вспомогательный метод createObject не в подклассах, а прям в абстрактном, это то что я и хотел. Спасибо.

Comment: @Klym: Пожалуйста!